# Create a column and in the same time update with Schema Builder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel using Schema Builder
how i can create a column and in the same time update his value whit the other value of the same table?
Its possible?
Thanks
Pseudo code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddSkuToWaranties extends Migration {

  public function up()
  {
    Schema::table('my_table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {
      $table->text('my_table_column');

      ///////////////////////
      $table->my_table_column = $table->my_other_table_column;
      ///////////////////////

    });
  }

  public function down()
  {
    Schema::table('my_table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropColumn('my_table_column');
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You can do it like this:

```
DB::table('my_table_name')
        ->update(array('my_table_column' => DB:raw('my_other_table_column')));
```

With this, you are using Laravel's Query Builder. It actually builds this query for you:

```
update my_table_name set my_table_column = my_other_table_column
```

Another solution is to just execute this raw query:

```
DB::update('update my_table_name set my_table_column = my_other_table_column');
```

As @lukasgeiter mentioned in a comment, you must place this code outside the closure, so this becomes the new `up()` method:

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('my_table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->text('my_table_column');
  });

  DB::table('my_table_name')
          ->update(array('my_table_column' => DB:raw('my_other_table_column')));
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to run this query outside of the `Schema::table()` closure.

Comment: @lukasgeiter You're right, thanks for mentioning, I will add it to the answer. However, I actually think that it will also work inside the closure.. But it is not the way to go indeed.